# Kivy Launcher : app crash with NameError : global name 'autoclass' is not defined

Tags: python, android, notifications, kivy

My kivy simple notifications app crashes on android, works fine on windows.

I am trying to make a simple application using kivy, plyer and oscpy modules to check the use of services on android.
Here is what the app does:
It has a button "set" that asks the service to pop a notification for the next minute
And another button "stop" to stop the service.

Here is the code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
from oscpy.client import OSCClient
from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from plyer import notification

SERVICE_NAME = u'{packagename}.Service{servicename}'.format(
            packagename=u'org.kivy.oscservice',
            servicename=u'Pong'
)

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setB=Button(text="set",size_hint=(.25,.2),pos_hint={"x":.3,"y":.4})
        self.add_widget(self.setB)
        self.setB.bind(on_press=self.set)
        self.lis=[]

        self.server=None
        self.server=server=OSCThreadServer()
        server.listen(
            address=b'localhost',
            port=30002,
            default=True
        )
        server.bind(b'/message',self.passnow)
        server.bind(b'/date',self.passnow)
        self.client=OSCClient(b'localhost',3000)
        self.start_service()
        self.stop=Button(text="Stop",size_hint=(.25,.2),pos_hint={"x":.3,"y":.1})
        self.add_widget(self.stop)
        self.stop.bind(on_press=self.stop_service)

    def start_service(self):
        if platform=='android':
            service=autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
            self.mActivity=autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
            argument=''
            service.start(self.mActivity,argument)
            self.service=service

        elif platform in ('linux','linux2','macos','win'):
            from runpy import run_path
            from threading import Thread
            self.service=Thread(
                target=run_path,
                args=['service.py'],
                kwargs={'run_name':'__main__'},
                daemon=True
            )
            self.service.start()
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "service start not implemented on this platform"
            )

    def stop_service(self):
        if self.service:
            if platform=="android":
                self.service.stop(self.mActivity)
            elif platform in ('linux','linux2','macos','win'):
                self.service.stop()
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError(
                    "service start not implemented on this platform"
                )
            self.service=None

    def set(self,button):
        time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if int(time.split(':')[1])+1 not in self.lis:
            self.lis.append(int(time.split(':')[1])+1)
        q=[]
        for p in range(len(self.lis)):
            if self.lis[p]==60:
                self.lis[p]=0
            if self.lis[p]<=int(time.split(':')[1]) and self.lis[p]!=0:
                q.append(p)
        for p in q:
            self.lis.remove(self.lis[p])
    #    print(self.lis)
        self.client.send_message(b'/ping',list(self.lis),)

    def passnow(self,message):
        pass

class PlyerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    now=PlyerApp()
    now.run()
```

and

service.py:

```
import datetime

from oscpy.server import OSCThreadServer
from oscpy.client import OSCClient
from plyer import notification
from time import sleep

notiflis=[]

CLIENT = OSCClient('localhost',3002)

def ping(*args):
    lis=[k for k in args]
    global notiflis
    notiflis=lis
    print(lis)
    CLIENT.send_message(
        b'/message',[],
    )

def plyer():
    now=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S").split(":")[1])
    #print(now,"   ",(now in notiflis))
    if now in notiflis:
        notification.notify(
        title=str('REMINDER AT '+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))),
        message="HERE IS YOUR REMINDER",
        timeout=15
        )
        notiflis.remove(now)
    else:
        return

if __name__=="__main__":
    SERVER = OSCThreadServer()
    SERVER.listen('localhost',port=3000,default=True)
    SERVER.bind(b'/ping',ping)
    while True:
        plyer()
        sleep(.9)
```

This works fine on windows
but when i try to run it on android using Kivy Launcher, it crashes after loading with the error:

> NameError: global name 'autoclass' is not defined

autoclass() is used in main.py in the line :

```
    def start_service(self):
        if platform=='android':
>            service=autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
```

Can someone please tell me why the error is occurring and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> This works fine on windows but when i try to run it on android

It "works" only in the sense that you don't run this line on windows.

The problem is that you failed to import autoclass, import it from the `jnius` module.

Comment: I avoided importing it from jnius module as I couldn't install pyjnius on my system. But after some searching, I understood that I don't need to explicitly install jnius. So I added the "from jnius import autoclass" just before using autoclass in the code. And it worked. Thanks.